# Ajax request image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make an AJAX request which contains a picture. Only the image is in a form, and need to be just the image.

```
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);

var data = {
  id: id,
  title:title,
  photo:formdata
};

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  url: '/my-url',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  processData: false,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log("error");
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

I'm getting the id and title with `.val();` and I want to keep this.., it's working fine for id and title, but I have no idea how to make work to send image to database.

Comment: So you want someone to write the server side part for you?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan noo..I just want to know why the image it's not passing..I'm looking at 'Request payload' and photo it's empty..

Comment: Show us the PHP code pls. I am bet, that your problem will be with the `formdata` part. That is the whole `form`.

Comment: don't use JSON.stringify, just pass the `FormData` object directly to `data`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because you're trying to append binary `FormData` to an object which is then serialised.

Instead you need to add the additional data to the `FormData` object so that it all can be encoded in the same way. Try this:

```
var form = $('form')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

formData.append('title', title);
formData.append('id', id);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  url: '/my-url',
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log("error");
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

Note that if the `id` and `title` values are retrieved from `input` elements within the `form`, then you don't even need the `append()` lines, as they will automatically be included in the `FormData` as you provided the `form` to the constructor.

Also make sure you run this code under the `submit` event of the `form` element and call `preventDefault`. Don't put this under the click of the `submit` button.